# error 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

We are in the process of creating a new site and up until now have had no issues. We are still able to access our admin panel, but yesterday this message showed up in place of the home page:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND ( a.publish_up = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR a.publish_up <= '2014-04-29 15:2' at line 1 SQL=

```
SELECT
  a.*,
  c.name as categoryname,
  c.id as categoryid,
  c.alias as categoryalias,
  c.params as categoryparams
FROM
  am4xy_k2_items as a
  LEFT JOIN am4xy_k2_categories c ON c.id = a.catid
WHERE
  a.published = 1
  AND a.access IN(1,1)
  AND a.trash = 0
  AND c.published = 1
  AND c.access IN(1,1)
  AND c.trash = 0
  AND a.catid IN()
  AND ( a.publish_up = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR a.publish_up <= '2014-04-29 15:25:15' )
  AND ( a.publish_down = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR a.publish_down >= '2014-04-29 15:25:15' )
ORDER BY a.created ASC
LIMIT 0, 16
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The empty `IN ()` clause jumps right out. If you have a variable populating `catid IN (...)` you'll need to verify that it isn't empty.

Comment: Thanks! Where do I do these edits? I'm new to this and still kind of lost.

Comment: When you are in the edit window, format your linebreaks and indentation as they should be (I pulled yours out of the error message, which would otherwise be unformatted). Highlight blocks of code and do `ctl-k` or click the `{}` toolbar in the editor to make a code block (indent 4 spaces) which gets you free syntax highlighting if the question is properly tagged.

Answer (score 1):

`IN()` cannot be empty:

```
AND a.catid IN()
```

You need to either add your missing values or remove it when it has none.

Comment: How do I know what the missing values are?

Comment: How is that query generated? Is it dynamic from a programming language? If so, it needs to be done when the query is constructed.

Comment: I'm not sure, this is on a Joomla 3.0 site. I'm assuming it is generated dynamically through php... but I could be completely wrong.

Comment: That may make it tricky to troubleshoot. But somewhere something is preventing that value from being provided to your query. Somehow you need to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: Is this something that I may be able to fix in phpmyadmin? I've deleted the k2 component that is mentioned in the error message. And it has deleted the database table that is associated with it, but I'm still getting these errors.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Wherever the query is generated is where you need to apply a fix. I don't know enough about Joomla to point you in the right direction. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It just happened to me that I left empty a required field called "Categories" in the Filter section in the !Cagenda component form in Joomla.

So the system build automatically the sql as `AND a.catid IN ()` with no values inside the "IN" statement.

Check all your fields have the required values ;)